# Swift3 - Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayI' (0x107009dd8) to 'NSDictionary' (0x10700a2d8)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

This is my function:

```
func locais(){
    var x: Int=0
    let tal = "http://localhost/cmios/api/mapa/\(id1)"
    print(tal);
    let url1 = URL(string: tal)
    let task1 = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url1!) { data, response, error in
        guard error == nil else{
            print(error!)
            return
        }
        guard let data = data else{
            print("Data is wrong")
            return
        }
        let json1 = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String:Any]
        let dados1 = json1["dados"] as? [[String: Any]]
```

The JSON that I want to return:

```
[{"id_animal":"9","latitude":"41.701497","longitude":"-8.834756","nome":"testeFinal"},{"id_animal":"10","latitude":"41.701497","longitude":"-8.834756","nome":"testeFinal"}]
```

And this is the error

```
Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayI' (0x107009dd8) to 'NSDictionary' (0x10700a2d8).
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: what is the input? What is *actually* contained in `data`?

Comment: It was already resolved! It was an error on php WS, thank's anyway!

Answer (score -1):

Get rid of the `as! [String:Any]` in your call to `JSONSerialization`. Then log the type you're actually getting back:

```
let json1 = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
print ("Returned data is type \(type(of: json1)")
```

That will tell you what you're actually getting.

You might also convert the `Data` you get back from the data task to a string and log that.

It sounds to me like the JSON you're receiving contains an `Array`, not a `Dictionary`